# Synonym suggestion for [tag:tides]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently (as of February 12, 2021), the yet undefined tag [tides](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tides) has only 27 occurences, which compares to the tag [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces) with 78 occurences. I suggest, that make [tides](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tides) a synonym of [tidal-forces](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tidal-forces) since tides are *always* caused by tidal forces, and both tags are therefore very closely linked. Any thoughts? Did I overlook something?

Comment: @called2voyage If there is no objection from anybody, would you mind defining the synonym, please?

Comment: So far it only has two upvotes and one of them is me, so I'd rather wait until we have a little more concurrence.

Comment: @called2voyage I guess, I am in general not too patient (as you might have noticed), but I am trying to slow down a bit for a while even though it is hard. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, [Astronomy's tag hygiene is actually within normal ranges](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1602/58) (unlike Space Exploration), so tag issues are not exactly an emergency. I do appreciate you being proactive though!

Comment: "Tides" are an earth science phenomenon. Tidal forces are an astrophysical one. Support the synonym

Comment: @JamesK *planetary* science: [Does Saturn raise tides on Titan's lakes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36632/7982) and [Do tides occur on planets like Neptune, having water?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29452/7982) and even [How high were the tides back when the Moon was much closer to Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39109/7982)

Comment: @called2voyage Do you think you could *now* (after some more comments and an answer) make `tides` a synonym of `tidal-forces`, please?

Comment: Merge complete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that tidal-forces concept is the driving force (literally) for ocean tides.

Bodies have *solid-tides* as well, so we should either have three tags or one.

I kind-of like the idea of having all three tags, but then what should we call the tides that the [moons of gas giant planets induce in the gas](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-can-tidal-heating-lower-ios-orbit/25083#comment42936_25083)? Or the tides produced in a star by a large companion (a close large planet or another stellar object)?

Hmmm...

Perhaps one tag for all is best, and I'll go along with tidal-forces as the tag's name.

---

Most of the tides questions would need to be retagged as tidal-forces instead; less than half are really about liquid tides, and note that while a few could have also been on-topic in Earth Science SE some really needed to be here, including

- [Does Saturn raise tides on Titan's lakes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36632/7982)
- [Do tides occur on planets like Neptune, having water?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29452/7982)
- [How high were the tides back when the Moon was much closer to Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39109/7982))

Comment: If all agree, I would start retagging once the synonym is created.

Comment: @B--rian does "I would" mean "somebody should" or "I will"?

Comment: I cannot define synonym (yet). Once I am one a non-mobile device *and* the synonym is created, I would start retagging, I meant.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks! You can consider pinging called2voyage under the question and ask if a sufficient "consensus threshold" has been achieved for it. But if the tags are merged then I don't know if re-tagging happens automatically or needs to be done manually. I still don't understand how tags work.

Comment: @B--rian my comment suggests "pinging called2voyage *under the question*" because if you do it there they will receive a notification of your comment. Since their username does not appear in comments under this answer (you probably had to type it manually, there was no autocomplete I'm guessing) then they will probably not receive a notification that you wrote a comment.here. From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) find [How do comment `@`replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080)